# Manually initiate login session using NestJS and Passport

Tags: node.js, nestjs, passport-saml

I'm looking for a way to programatically log in a fake user for development purposes. The end goal is that I open the app for demo/development purposes and there's a fake user forcibly logged in(this is turned off in production)

Currently, I have 3 sets of middleware running:

1. `express-session` - Sets up the session and session storage provider
2. Some custom middleware I wrote that just appends my dev user to `req.session.user`
3. `passport-saml` middleware that checks to see if a user is authenticated, and kicks them over to the SSO provider if not.

Right now, I can add some more middleware between 1 and 3 and see that my fake user is persisting in the session(at least for the duration of the request, anyway). However, clearly I'm not doing something that the `passport-saml` middleware is expecting to see because regardless of what I set in the session it always thinks I'm unauthenticated and redirects me to the SSO provider.

The first layer of middleware(`express-session`) looks like this:

```
session({
  secret: config.get('SESSION_SECRET'),
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
  },
  store,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
});
```

The second layer of middleware looks like this:

```
(req: Request, _: Response, next: NextFunction): void => {
  req.session.user = adminUser;
}
```

And the third layer of middleware is just passport middleware.

I did try calling `req.logIn` in step 2, but I got a message saying `passport.initialize() middleware not in use`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[nestjs-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-session) with a [custom passport strategy](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-custom/) turned out to be the solution